# Jenkinsfile: Curl logs from previous (still running) stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm in a process of migrating from freestyle jobs chained into pipeline to have the pipeline in a Jenkinsfile.

My current pipeline will execute 2 jobs in parallel, one will create a tunnel to database (with a randomly generated port) and the next job needs to get this port number, so I'm performing a curl command and reading the console of the `create-db-tunnel` job and storing the port number. The `create-db-tunnel` needs to keep running as the follow up job is connecting to the database and is taking DB dump. This is the curl command which I run on the second job and which is returning the randomly generated port number from the established DB tunnel:

`Port=$(curl -u ${USERNAME}:${TOKEN} http://myjenkinsurl.com/job/create-db-tunnel/lastBuild/consoleText | grep Port | grep -Eo '[0-9]{3,5}')`

I wonder if there is anything similar I can use in Jenkinsfile? I currently have the 2 jobs triggered in parallel, but since the `create-db-tunnel` is no longer a freestyle job, I'm not sure if I can get the port number still? I can confirm that the console logs for the `db_tunnel` stage has the port number in there, just not sure how can I query that console. Here is my jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
    APTIBLE_LOGIN = credentials('aptible')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            parallel {
                // run db_tunnel and get_port in parralel 
                stage ('db_tunnel') {
                    steps {
                        sh """
                          export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
                          aptible login --email=$APTIBLE_LOGIN_USR --password=$APTIBLE_LOGIN_PSW
                          aptible db:tunnel postgres-prod & sleep 30s
                        """
                    }
                }
                stage('get_port') {
                    steps {
                        sh """
                          sleep 15s
                          //this will not work
                          Port=$(curl -u ${USERNAME}:${TOKEN} http://myjenkinsurl.com/job/db_tunnel/lastBuild/consoleText | grep Port | grep -Eo '[0-9]{3,5}')
                          echo "Port=$Port" > port.txt
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a solution to my question - it was a very similar curl command I had to run and I'm now getting the desired port number I needed. Here is the jenkinsfile if someone is interested:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
    APTIBLE_LOGIN = credentials('aptible')
    JENKINS_TOKEN = credentials('jenkins')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            parallel {
                // run db_tunnel and get_port in parralel 
                stage ('db_tunnel') {
                    steps {
                        sh """
                          export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
                          aptible login --email=$APTIBLE_LOGIN_USR --password=$APTIBLE_LOGIN_PSW
                          aptible db:tunnel postgres-prod & sleep 30s
                        """
                    }
                }
                stage('get_port') {
                    steps {
                        sh """
                          sleep 20
                          Port=\$(curl -u $JENKINS_TOKEN_USR:$JENKINS_TOKEN_PSW http://myjenkinsurl.com/job/schema-archive-jenkinsfile/lastBuild/consoleText | grep Port | grep -Eo '[0-9]{3,5}')
                          echo "Port=\$Port" > port.txt
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```